# How to zoom image from gridview when clicked ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview

I have used img src inside asp.net gridview and it loads image from DB and itworks but problem is that i want to appear larger on screen when clicked but I can't achieve that. I wrote a code which zooms the image inside gridview but i don't want that, I want to appear it larger outside gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Letter Copy">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <img src='../SiteImages/<%# Eval("OutgoingLetterCopy") %>' width="20" height="20"
                                                                onmouseover="ShowFull(this)" onmouseout="ShowActual(this)" />
                                                            <%--<asp:ImageButton ID="btnOutgoingLetterCopy" runat="server" ImageUrl='../SiteImages/<%# Eval("OutgoingLetterCopy") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ControlStyle-Width="20px" ControlStyle-Height="20px" />--%>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

code:

```
function ShowFull(ctrl) {
            ctrl.style.height = '280px';
            ctrl.style.width = '280px';
        }

        function ShowActual(ctrl) {
            ctrl.style.height = '20px';
            ctrl.style.width = '20px';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a CSS scale transformation.  So toggle a css class on the image.

For example, if your image tag has class `.enlarge`:

```
.enlarge:hover {
transform:scale(2,2);
transform-origin:0 0;
```

}

You can check this site out for specifics:

http://www.cssportal.com/graphics/enlarge-image.php